# Swift code in same scope executed different amount of times

Tags: swift

I am making an app for IOS in Swift using Xcode 7.1.0

I have a switch case inside a function.
When I placed breakpoint I noticed that within a case one line of code is executed twice every time the case is executed. It seems to be just that single line, the rest is executed only once (like it should).

The line with the jsonobject is executed just once.
The line with the saveCurrentMeasurementDetailsToCoreData function is executed twice.

How is this even possible?

This is my code:

```
private func apiReceivedDetailData(state: ApiCall.ApiState, data : AnyObject){
    switch state{
    case ApiCall.ApiState.Successful:

        // Put the values in the researchmodel and update the table with this global measurement information
        let jsonObject : NSObject = data as! NSObject


        //save all data of current measurement to CoreData
        MeasurementRepository.Instance.saveCurrentMeasurementDetailsToCoreData()

    case ApiCall.ApiState.InvalidCredentials:
        showFailure(data as! String)

    case ApiCall.ApiState.NoConnection:
        showFailure(data as! String)

    default:
        showFailure("Onbekende fout opgetreden")

    }
}
```

First a call to the api is done:

```
func getMesDetailData() {
    let apiCall = ApiCall()
    apiCall.createCall(ApiCall.ApiCall.Meting, id: _researchModel.Id)
    apiCall.dataAvailable = apiReceivedDetailData
}

func createCall(apiCall : ApiCall, id : Int){
    createCall(apiCall, id : id, postString : nil)
}

func createCall(apiCall : ApiCall, id : Int?, postString : String?){


    var url : NSURL

    if id == nil{
        url = NSURL(string: _apiUrl + connectToApi(apiCall))!
    }
    else{
        url = NSURL(string: _apiUrl + connectToApi(apiCall) + String(id!))!
    }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    if postString != nil {

        let postData : NSData = (postString! as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        // create the request
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
        request.HTTPBody = postData
    }

    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
}

private func connectToApi(apiCall : ApiCall) -> String{
    switch apiCall {
    case .Meting:
        return "/meting/"
    case .LastMeting:
        return "/meting/last"
    case .Login:
        return "/login/"
    case .Training:
        return "/training/"
    case .Sport:
        return "/sport/"
    case .Type:
        return "/type/"
    case .Goal:
        return "/goal/"
    default:
        return ""

    }
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {

    switch (_responseCode){
    case 200, 201, 400:
        // Succesfull
        var jsonResult: AnyObject? = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(_data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

        if jsonResult == nil {
            jsonResult = ""
        }

        dataAvailable!(
            state: _responseCode != 400 ? ApiState.Successful : ApiState.BadRequest,
            data: jsonResult!
        )
    case 403:
        // Faulty credentials
        dataAvailable!(state: ApiState.InvalidCredentials, data: _faultCredentialsMessage)
    case 429:
        // Too many requests
        dataAvailable!(state: ApiState.TooManyRequests, data: _tooManyRequestsMessage)
    default:
        // Unknow status code
        let responseMessage = _unknowStatusCode + " Status code: " + String(_responseCode)
        dataAvailable!(state: ApiState.UnknowStatusCode, data: responseMessage)
    }

}
```

Comment: Check the calls for the method which has the switch. I think it is being called twice when your API call succeeds.

Comment: @NSNoob the line with "let jsonObject : NSObject = data as! NSObject"
is called only once

Comment: Maybe check for recursion in `MeasurementRepository.Instance.saveCurrentMeasurementDetailsToCoreData()`.

Comment: Yes I got that. I am asking you to look for places from where this method is being called. Just to be sure.

Comment: @sunshine saveCurrentMeasurementsDetailsToCoreData() is not recursive

Comment: @sunshine Possible but what are the odds that `saveCurrentMeasurementDetailsToCoreData()` is calling the method where this switch exists? To do that he first needs to figure out from where is he calling the switch and how many times.

Comment: If it is not recursive I would just obey the Xcode debugger, it is probably stepping when it calls the method and second time when it comes back to you.

Comment: @NSNoob the method which contains the switch is called only once

Comment: @SebastiaanHoedeman and where are you calling that? During/Before/After making the Asynchronous/Synchronous call to your API? It might be due to Asynchronous call and improper placement of call within/without the block. More data would be helpful to other readers as well. Do add the call block to your post as well.